# Multiple metrics projects after upgrade

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, okd

I've just upgraded OKD to version 3.11 and I'm little confused by the number of metrics/monitoring projects:

- openshift-infra
- openshift-metrics
- openshift-metrics-server
- openshift-monitoring

Openshift-infra is the old one with hawkular and cassandra, which presents metrics in projects (resource usage per pod etc.). Openshift-monitoring is the new one used by Cluster Console for alerting. But, what are the projects openhift-metrics and openshift-metrics-server used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the projects are each usage for as following list

- `openshift-infra` : for cluster metrics stack (hawkular/heapster/cassandra)
- `openshift-metrics` : for old standalone prometheus [related bugreport](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1569400)
- `openshift-metrics-server` : for metrics server which will be replaced with heaster [heaster item in refer ocp v3.11 release note](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/release_notes/ocp_3_11_release_notes.html#ocp-311-major-changes-in-40)
- `openshift-monitoring` : for new Prometheus Cluster monitoring stack

Comment: So if I understand correct, openshift-metrics-server will replace heapster in next version?
I've removed openshift-metrics as I don't need standalone prometheus anymore. Thanks.